# Merge all dataframes together in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several CSV files in a certain path. I would like to add them all together, I did this laboriously with a function and assigned the individual arrays to the dataframe.
Is there an option to do everything in a for loop?
So I don't have to do `df1 = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILES[0]` and `frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4]`?

As soon as I try to loop reading in a for, I get an error.

How can I improve this code by not referring to the individual arrays `CSV_FILES[0]` , but doing everything in a loop?

```
PATH = ''
def find_csv(path):
    csv_files = []
    print("Looking for files at ", path)
    for file in Path(path).glob('*.csv'):
        csv_files.append(str(file)) 
    print("Found ", len(csv_files), " csv files")
    return csv_files

CSV_FILES = find_csv(PATH)


df1 = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILES[0])
df2 = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILES[1])
df3 = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILES[2])
df4 = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILES[3])

frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create list of DataFrames, change:

```
csv_files.append(str(file))
```

to:

```
csv_files.append(pd.read_csv(str(file)))
```

And then join them together:

```
df = pd.concat(CSV_FILES)
```